# Do I need a Node.js Server as well as Laravel Echo Server?

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io

I am struggling to get broadcasting working with Laravel. I am working with multiple tutorials because none of them fully explain everything I need to understand. I just read a tutorial that included setting up a Node.js Server with ioredis but I assumed that Laravel Echo Server is doing that job already. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a node.js server. You can use laravel-websockets package which exempts you from using any kind of broadcasting server.
I'm using it for broadcasting with laravel Echo and it's really simple to set up by following installation instructions.

In fact, the best option is to set it up with pusher.

https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with laravel echo server, redis, and  phpredis last night. It took the whole day and I wasn't done til 5:30am thanks to struggling to work out how to authenticate the channel requests from laravel echo server.